# I can't seem to get the right mysql command for inserting from two tables into a 3rd table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to do an insert from two tables into a third table with one sql command.  The following doesn't work.  If anyone has a suggestion that would be great.

```
INSERT INTO table3(table1_id, table2_id) SELECT (table1_id, table2_id) FROM (table1,table2);
```

Comment: Do you really intend a Cartesian join between table1 and table2?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> INSERT INTO table3(table1_id, table2_id)
> SELECT (table1.table1_id, table2.table2_id)
> FROM table1, table2;
> ```

Comment: The parentheses around the column list in the select statement are totally useless. And I'm pretty sure a cartesian product of the two tables is not what the OP had in mind.

Comment: Yea, I know.  I was a tad lazy and just copied OP's query and made the required modifications.  Since there's nothing wrong with that query, didn't bother changing it. As for the cartesian product, if you look at the OP's question and the SQL query, it seems that's what he/she wants.